# Need help creating curves based on set keyframe positions (maya/python)

Tags: python, animation, maya, curve, keyframe

I'm trying to create a tool in maya using python that creates curves based on an objects keyframe positions. The end goal is to create different animation curves that the object can blend between so as to create adjustments to the main animation. Here's what I have so far. It creates a curve that follows the path of motion but it's not based on keyframe position. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def createAnimCurve( startFrame, endFrame, numCV, object ):
    curveCVstep = ((endFrame - startFrame)+startFrame)/numCV
    points = []
    for step in range( startFrame, endFrame, int(curveCVstep)):
        # Moves throughout the specified timeline to find point results
        cmds.currentTime( step )
        # Queries the pivot position to draw the curve relative to the controller
        xpos = cmds.xform( object,q=1,ws=1,rp=1 )
        # convert the tuple (vector) to a string
        points.append(xpos)
    cmds.curve(d=3, ws=True, p=points, n=object+'_xPath')

createAnimCurve(1,24,12,"L_hand_CTL")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you'll want to iterate through key frames (using [keyframe](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/keyframe.html#flagtimeChange) timeChange query) rather than a start/end range stepping numCvs.

```
keyframes = sorted(list(set(cmds.keyframe(object, q=True, timeChange=True))))
```

Also, avoid using [object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=object#object) as a variable name it's a built-in.

Comment: That sounds like what I need but when looking at the output it seems to be looping the few keyframes over and over. Here's an example of what I mean. 
[1.0, 5.0, 9.0, 13.0, 17.0, 21.0, 24.0, 1.0, 5.0, 9.0, 13.0, 17.0, 21.0, 24.0, 1.0, 5.0, 9.0, 13.0, 17.0, 21.0, 24.0, 1.0, 5.0, 9.0, 13.0, 17.0, 21.0, 24.0, 1.0, 5.0, 9.0, 13.0, 17.0, 21.0, 24.0, 1.0, 5.0, 9.0, 13.0, 17.0, 21.0, 24.0, 1.0, 5.0, 9.0, 13.0, 17.0, 21.0, 24.0, 1.0, 5.0, 9.0, 13.0, 17.0, 21.0, 24.0, 1.0, 5.0, 9.0, 13.0, 17.0, 21.0, 24.0]
Also thank you I'll make sure to change the object variable to something else.

Comment: Ah of course, it'll be giving you time changes for each curve. Either pass an animCurve if your after keyframes per abimCurve or for all keyframes sort a set (see edit).

Comment: Or you could use a list comprehension to check each value is unique prior to appending for instances where you cannot rely on sorting.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly to clean out the results you put the values into a set which you then created into a list which was then sorted? Could you explain how that works? I'm sure this will help out down the road.

Comment: Yes. A set is an unordered collection of elements. Each element is unique and must be hashable. As a set is unordered we cast it to a list (it's still a collection) and then sort that list. See http://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set

Comment: Thank you for the help. It's definitely what I need to start creating this tool!

Comment: Note that if you're using animation layers this only returns the keyframes from the currently selected animation layer. On top of that the keyframe command has no parameter to select a specific animation layer (whereas setKeyframe has it for example) ...